Round numerical values in an 'enrichResult' class object?
It's pretty straightforward the question.
I work with an enrichResult created from the enrichDO function. The round function doesn't work directly, and the dplyr package seems to not work with these objects. I want to round all numerical arguments as if it were a dataframe with different class columns i.e.:
#something similar to this code (this doesn`t work)
df  %>%  dplyr::mutate_if(is.numeric, round, digits = 3)


Here the data to run possible code
# Simulate data
set.seed(123)  # for reproducibility
n <- 10  # number of observations
simulated_data <- data.frame(
  ID = paste0("DOID:", sample(1000:9999, n, replace = TRUE)),
  Description = paste0("Description", 1:n),
  GeneRatio = paste(sample(1:10, n, replace = TRUE), "/", sample(10:20, n, replace = TRUE)),
  BgRatio = paste(sample(100:200, n, replace = TRUE), "/", sample(1000:2000, n, replace = TRUE)),
  pvalue = runif(n, 0, 1),
  p.adjust = runif(n, 0, 1),
  qvalue = runif(n, 0, 1),
  geneID = paste0("Gene", sample(1:100, n, replace = TRUE))
)

# Load the DOSE package for the enrichResult class
library(DOSE)

# Create an enrichResult object
edo_example <- new("enrichResult", result = simulated_data, 
           pvalueCutoff = 0.05, pAdjustMethod = "BH", qvalueCutoff = 0.05)


